# Good open source analytics/stats software in PHP?

Tags: php, open-source, analytics, statistics

The url shortening service I'm building needs to display some basic click stats to users: # of clicks, conversions, referring domains, and country (filterable by a date range). I'll possibly want more advanced stats in the future.

Is there existing open source software that will allow me to pass events to it and then easily display a bar or line graph of that event (for example, a line graph of "conversions" between two specified dates). It seems like something like this should exist and would be much easier then building the whole thing from scratch.

I know there are graphing scripts, but that still requires me to format the data (usually as an xml file) and then pass it to the graph. I'm looking for something a bit more complete, which I can just feed the events and then it does everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every kind of software I can image will need you to generate the data you want to plot.

At this point, you have two possibilities:

- Use a third party solution for your stats (such as [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics))
- Use [a library](http://highcharts.com/) to show your data graphically

The first solution will be easy to use, but it won't be flexible.
The second one will be a bit harder (not too much), but you'll decide what to plot and how.

I've recently started [an open source project](http://aloiroberto.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/highcharts-php-library/) to make the highcharts plotting easier from php. You might want to have a look to it.

Comment: Just came across http://piwik.org which is more what I'm looking for. I feed it events, it displays the data. I don't need to worry about complex sql queries, caching, etc.. Although it doesn't yet support custom date ranges so I'm still looking.

Comment: [Custom date ranges in Piwik (link)](http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/#faq_33)

Answer (score 8):

There are a large number of packages that do what you want. The most popular ones are:

- [Cobub Razor](http://www.cobub.com/) (Redis supported for high performance)
- [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)
- [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/)
- [TraceWatch](http://www.tracewatch.com/)

They all require a database connection (mostly MySQL) to collect and store the data, which can be a performance problem when your service becomes popular.

One of the simpler packages that is file-based is

- [BBClone](http://www.bbclone.de/)

The features of file-based solutions are generally more limited.

Comment: Here is another project worth checking out. http://phpwebstats.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

[AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is the best open source analytics/stats software I have used.  Recently we have moved away AWStats and we are using Google Analytics,  but that is because we are also using Google Adwords.  AWStats is a great program.

Comment: AWStats is written in Perl though, not PHP.