# How can I track user visit in my website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, php-5.3

How can I track user visit in my website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good open source analytics/stats software in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382066/good-open-source-analytics-stats-software-in-php)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use analytics from Google :)

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: Just have in mind that Google Analytics will count the visits but would not show https sites as referrals in the stats. For more info you can check http://ilian.i-n-i.org/google-analytics-referring-sites-and-https/

Comment: If your based in the EU you need to be aware of the new cookie regulations: http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies.aspx & http://technicallysqueaking.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/eu-cookie-legislation-and-google.html

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot Great Analytics tools out there, with Google Analytics [ http://www.google.com/analytics/ ] being one of the best and one of the most common, give it a try, it will probably fulfill your needs. The Downside of GA is its somewhat unclear Data Policy and the Fact that the Data is not real Time, for example, you can't specifically track Actions of a single User, thats why I for some Projects use PIWIK [ http://piwik.org/ ].

Answer (score 1):

I also like sitemeter:

http://www.sitemeter.com/

there is a free version available, and if you want to use basic analytics I find it easier than google's analytics.